# installation of SQL server in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dependencies

1. `wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server`

// i have tried to install sql server following the above commands in my newly installed ubuntu 22.04 machine and when i run the following command am stuck...

**sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup**
this is the error am getting from terminal

```
patrick@patrick-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IGM:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
patrick@patrick-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IGM:~$ cd /opt
```

Please i beg from the community to help me unlock this stalemate.. or lather i be helped how i can install sql to my newly installed ubuntu 22.04  machine with ease .. or the entire procedure... or what i should do....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure you should be using the `ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019.list` repository file when you OS is actually ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Am Not even sure which server i should actually use please may i be helped how to solve my issue .. all i want is sql in my machine... I have really struggled before i get here

Comment: Do you just want SQL, or MSSQL specifically?

Comment: @steeldriver SQL Server is MSSQL ;-)

Comment: You need either https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/23.04/  or https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04

Comment: I Need SQL ... Kindly assist me with the procedure.

Comment: @user2601069 hmm what is unc;ear? use 1 of the 2 links to replace your download.The rest is the same.

Comment: Thanks i have received those files but am abit confused how to use them in the termial