# How do I install MSSQL Server on Ubuntu

Tags: mssql

I am 74 years old and an old Windows user (dating back to MS-DOS 3.0 days) I am dumping Windows 10 and moving over to a Linux OS. I have chosen Ubuntu for my migration.

Here is my situation. I am using VMWare workstation 17 in Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04 as my learning environment. I have a need to run MSSQL Server in this environment. I have tried this several times without success. I know I am missing something.

I am looking for a complete set of installation instructions, including version to version advice, all pre-installation requirements i.e. drivers(ODBC), Libraries, etc. I am a heavy user of MS-SQL Server for my personal use. If it won't work in VMWare, please let me know.

Comment: there you go - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @graham though I was inclined to make the same suggestion, OP explicitly asks for MS-SQL...(here is a fist google on it ...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2004) though I do prefer MariaDB for my personal and work use.

Comment: @Bruni oops then [this one](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-microsoft-sql-server-on-ubuntu-linux/) perhaps?

Comment: Microsoft’s ODBC driver for Linux tends to break with every major update. What I do is run SQL Server in a Docker container. This allows isolation from the OS and offers a little bit of portability for smaller databases.

Comment: @matigo  can confirm. Stay with Ubuntu LTS. don't use intermidiates.  The to go to faq is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2004 AU soecific (but for 22.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464703/installation-of-sql-server-in-ubuntu-22-04 )  and welcome :D My windows exp ended with XP bus also started with dos ;-)  (xenix (the MS version) was my 1st unix :D )  Mind I would do it diffferently: install Windows INSIDE Ubuntu and stick sql server in there.